# VBA: Function for returning specific Outlook folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to search for specific emails in specific folders, but these folders have different **sub-levels** and not all the same parent folder.

So I like to have a function that will simply give me the Outlook folder object for a given folder name.

Does something like this exists?

```
FindFolder(str_FolderName As String) As Outlook.Folder
```

So that I can just write

```
objFolder = FindFolder("MyFolder")
```

All the solutions I´ve found or come up with weren´t as flexible as needed.

Comment: folders can have the same name just with different parent folders.  How are you going to distinguish if it is the folder you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a counterpart of `MAPIFolder.FullFolderPath` property (returns something like `\\user@domain.name\RSS Feeds\Stack Overflow`) to return a folder given its path?

You can write a function that converts the path to an array/list and recursively processes the list starting with `Namespace.Folders` collection. You will need to take care of special character encoding (e.g. %20 for " ").

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetFolderFromPath` function.

Comment: No, that's not really what I am looking for. I have a function FindEmail(objFolder, strSearch) that returns me emails for given search strings and a given folder. I just dont want to set every folder object manually and like a function to return me the correct folder object for a given folder name.

Comment: Just a folder name? How would you possibly make it work? There can be multiple folders on multiple levels with the same name even in a single store.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function due to to the fact that folders with the same name can exists at different levels in the tree. For example, a folder may contain a child folder with the same name. What folder should be returned then? A parent or child folder?

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.